# Laravel Routes ordering

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, url-routing, laravel-routing

I am using Laravel 4.2 on a project.

I have setup routes for :

**slug, category, services**

In terms of ordering, If I move services above slug, It can't find the slug and ultimately goes to to the services controller and same, If I keep the slug method above services. It can't find that either.

My current routes is as follows :

```
Route::get('{slug?}', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('{category?}', 'HomeController@category');
Route::get('{services?}', 'ServicesController@index');
```

Is there a way to fix this, The category one works fine, But switching slug and services around creates a problem.

Thanks

Comment: It's probably because your routes are all the same in theory, can't you do something like `/category/{category}` or `/services/{service}`. Just to test? Bearing in mind i'm new to laravel lol

Comment: Just tried that @AndyHolmes the services one just doesn't work. It's being routed to the slug route

Comment: You also have to put the most specific route first, otherwise the more general one will be applied, because `{slug?}` applies to literally anything you pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They way you wrote the routes, Laravel has no way to tell which request should go to which route, because you wrote three routes with one optional parameter which could be anything. 
The way routing works is: it applies the first route that matches the pattern. That is why when it hits the first route pattern that says "one param that can be anything" it picks that route.

You should give Laravel some kind of hint, like:

```
Route::get('{slug?}', 'HomeController@index')->where('slug', '(blog|home|contact)');

Route::get('/category/{category?}', 'HomeController@category');

Route::get('/services/{services?}', 'ServicesController@index');
```

If you restrict the possible values or if you put additional part in the URL, Laravel will be able to recognize which route should go to which handler.

Take a look at the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters) to get more ideas

Comment: Thanks for that! The slug & category ones' work, But the services one still doesn't work. I've tried ->where('slug', '[A-Za-z]+'); But no luck!

Comment: `[A-Za-z]+` means where slug has any capitalcase or lowercase letter and has minimum length of 1.

Comment: So how do I get any URL barring category & services. To go go HomeController@index the docs' unfortunatley are not helping.

Comment: You should put your most generic route last (in this case, `slug`) or constrain the values with a `where` statement. But keep in mind that anything that does not match the routes above it, it will fallback to it since it really means anything that is a string of letters

Comment: I think the where-> route would be best, But the problem I have is that is going to be variable. For example a slug would look like : koodoo-pack or my-space-pack

Comment: put it as last one in your routes, since you want it to be generic. Remember that Laravel applies the first pattern that matches.

Comment: Great! That's done the trick! Your answer plus moving it to the base of my routes file has it all working. Many Thanks!